# STM32F105 stop executing after 16 seconds

Tags: stm32, can, stm32cubemx

I'm facing an issue with an STM32F105 microcontroller which with a simple code executing in a while loop it stops after 16 second
here is code which I don't think there is a problem with the code since it runs fine on STM32F103

```
while (1)
  {
      uint8_t frame[8] = {'H','E','L','L','O','W','O','R'};
      CAN1_TX(0x110110,8,frame);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1);
      HAL_Delay(500);
      CAN1_TX(0x110110,8,frame);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
      HAL_Delay(500);
  }

void CAN1_TX(uint32_t id,uint32_t dlc,uint8_t frame[8]){
    char msg[50];
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
    uint32_t TxMailbox;
    TxHeader.DLC = dlc;
    TxHeader.ExtId = id;
    TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;
    TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    if(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, frame,&TxMailbox) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
    }

    while(HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan1, TxMailbox));
}
```

The two leds blinks for 16 seconds and then they stop.
When I changed the delay to 500 it blinks now for 8 seconds only.
The problem is from the CAN_TX functions the problem only happens when CAN1_TX or CAN2_TX added
Debugging didn't help after that 8 seconds the debugger don't show any problem or where it is hanging

EDITED**
Now after more digging.I changed the CAN mode to LOOPBACK and the problem disapeared it seems that the problem only happens on normal mode but why ?  when I switch back to normal mode the problem came back
please note that the CAN_TX does not work now while it was sending frames yesterday

here is the clock config in case it has anything to do with this issue[image: Clock Configuration]

Comment: Is there a watchdog timer set to 16 seconds by any chance?

Comment: Post the whole code. And tell which compiler or IDE or libraries you use. And on which board the STM32F105 is. Schematics, etc.

Comment: You already have an outstanding question here, solve that problem first so that you can see what is going on. [STM32F10x microcontroller debugging problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511796/stm32f10x-microcontroller-debugging-problem)

Comment: I'm using STM32CubeIDE chosen STM32F105 and the activated the GPIO pins for the LEDs and added those two lines of code so no more code is added other than the IDE boilerplate

Comment: Probably you are building invalid code with wrong settings for the MCU... it really looks like this is *one problem, not two*.   Rather obviously, the code you have posted here is grossly incomplete and not remotely valid.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for your reply. I have solved the debugging problem and I debugged it but can't figure out where is the problem.After the 16th while loop the debugger keeps running but the code is not executing anymore
what's more weird is when changed the delay to 500ms now it stop executing after 8 seconds only.can I know somehow where the code runing is when it breaks away from the while loop ?

Comment: I've edited the question it seems that the problem is from CAN_TX function when removed the code execute infinitly but there is no error and even while debugging when the code execution stop the micro still runing but the code is not executing

Comment: Now after more digging.I changed the CAN mode to LOOPBACK and the problem disapeared it seems that the problem only happens on normal mode but why ?